# Array of a single field

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm quite confused on how to access the values of a field, i have 2 fields which accepts several inputs let's call it `r_id[ ]` and `qty[ ]` and i need to access each of their values independently

now supposedly this should loop depending on how many `r_id's` are inside the input post

```
foreach ($_POST['r_id'] as $row)
```

`r_id` is used to verify how many qty s should i put on a `r_id`

input e.g:

```
r_id=1,2
qty=3,16
```

what should happen is on a row with an `r_id` of 1 i will take the old qty with a sample value of 5 and minus the new `qty 3` and then on the second iteration `r_id 2` old value of qty minus new `qty 16` and so on

these are the forms i used

```
<input type="text" name="r_id[]" class="form-control inline" value="" required>
<input type="number" step="0.001" name="qty[]" class="form-control inline" value="" required>
```

i made a javascript to add similar fields up to 10 so that explains why i use an array

Comment: `r_id=1,2` is not an array

Comment: This is not clear - please edit to clarify, make sure you include the form html that makes the post request

Comment: @RiggsFolly that's only a sample input so basically i put 1 and 2 on different fields with same name by use of 'name[   ]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To process those 2 HTML array fields from the $_POST array you need to do something like this :

Remember both `$_POST['r_id']` and `$_POST['qty']` are arrays and they should be delivered to you in the same order they appear on the HTML page. So you can process over one of them in a foreach and then address the other directly

So as a simple example of looking at what was entered :-

```
foreach ($_POST['r_id'] as $idx => $id) {
    echo 'r_id - ' . $id . ' was entered with qty ' . $_POST['qty'][$idx];
}
```

Comment: Haaa _copy/paste will get me every time_ Thanks

Comment: `$idx` is the index of the `$_POST['r_id']` So if you enter 2 `r_id` on the screen and 2 `qty` both arrays will have 2 occurances `$idx` would be 0 then 1 Remember `$_POST` is an array but also `$_POST['r_id']` is also an array. An array within an array